# AVAudioSession Not Play Sound Automatically When Home Button Press

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudiosession

I am playing Videos in UIWebView and use below code for play its audio in background.

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

The problem is that when i press Home Button AVAudioSession not play music automatically until i press on play button in Toggle or control center menu. 
Also when i press on Play button it hides seek track duration and music info, when i pause music then it show.

Can anyone please tell me how i can fix it?
Thanks